# Limiting the access of JNI file access to "just" one folder

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-security

If I launch some C code with the JNI in my Android application, is there a way I could limit that C code to access only a specific folder in my application folder, so sandboxing it to just a specific sub-folder of my application folder?

From my understanding the native C code invoking syscalls in the context of a Android application is sandboxed to the files of that application, following the general application sandboxing design. But I would like to specify that the C code and all of its shared libraries will only be able to access i.e. the "c_storage" folder within my application storage.

I tried with the overriding the POSIX symbols, this works but of course a shared module could work around that with dlsym.

Comment: Why do you need such thing? If you are in control of that C code, then you should be pretty sure that it won't access something you don't want.

Comment: If you start including dependencies you are never sure...

Comment: By "dependencies" you mean the shared libraries of the C code you wrote?
What is your real use case? Why do you need to be such paranoid about that?
If so, the first step should be not to use unsafe languages like C (preferably Rust should be used instead) and only then consider next steps.